# Cant get dropdown open window work in chrome

Tags: jquery, select, dropdown

i have a page where it has the same block of form fields many times. Depending a dropd down list selection is showing the specific form. The following code is working ok in FF but is not working in chrome.

```
 function goToNewPage(dropdownlist) {var url = dropdownlist.value; if (url != "") { window.open(url); } }
```

and the following code is being repeated many times in the page

```
<div class="pull-right" style="padding:0px 13px 2px 0px;"><label for="domcontacts">{$LANG.domaincontactinfo}</label>
                    <select id="domcontacts">
                     <option menuitemname="Reg-C" href="/#tabRegc" class="list-group-item" data-toggle="tab" value="/#tabRegc">{$LANG.rcdom_regcdetails}</option>
                     <option menuitemname="Admin-C" href="/#tabAdminc" class="list-group-item" data-toggle="tab" value="/#tabAdminc">{$LANG.rcdom_admincdetails}</option>                         
                     <option menuitemname="Tech-C" href="/#tabTechc" class="list-group-item" data-toggle="tab" value="/#tabTechc">{$LANG.rcdom_techcdetails}</option>
                     <option menuitemname="Bill-C" href="/#tabBillc" class="list-group-item" data-toggle="tab" value="/#tabBillc">{$LANG.rcdom_billcdetails}</option>
                    </select></div>
```

Comment: where are you calling goToNewPage function

Comment: In the same html page between <script></script> tags.